# How to load Orocos Component by loadComponent function?

Tags: ros, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed:
http://rtt-lwr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutos/orocos-tuto.html

instructions:

```
cd ~/code/ros_kinetic/src/
catkin_create_pkg my_component rtt_ros roscpp ocl rtt_sensor_msgs
roscd my_component
```

src:

```
vim src/basic_orocos_rtt.cpp
#include <rtt/RTT.hpp>
#include <rtt/TaskContext.hpp>
#include <rtt/Component.hpp>
#include <rtt/Logger.hpp>

class MyComponent : public RTT::TaskContext
{
   public:
   // Constructor
   // That's the name you're gonna pass as first argument of "loadComponent"
   MyComponent(const std::string& name):
   RTT::TaskContext(name)
   {
        RTT::log(RTT::Info) << "Constructing ! " << RTT::endlog();
   }

   // The function called when writing my_component.configure()
   bool configureHook()
   {
        RTT::log(RTT::Info) << "Configuring  ! " << RTT::endlog();
        return true;
   }

   // The function called (periodically or not) when calling my_component.start()
   void updateHook()
   {
        RTT::log(RTT::Info) << "Updating ! " << RTT::endlog();
   }
};
ORO_CREATE_COMPONENT(MyComponent) //Let Orocos know how to build this component
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_component)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rtt_sensor_msgs
  rtt_ros
  cmake_modules
)
## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
# )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES sam_basic_orocos_rtt
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rtt_ros_integration
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${USE_OROCOS_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/sam_basic_orocos_rtt.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
# add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/sam_basic_orocos_rtt_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_sam_basic_orocos_rtt.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)

orocos_component(my_component src/basic_orocos_rtt.cpp)
set_property(TARGET my_component APPEND
        PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS RTT_COMPONENT)

target_link_libraries(my_component
    ${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
# orocos_install_headers(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME})
orocos_generate_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include)
```

Test:

```
deployer

Deployer [S]> loadComponent("my_component","MyComponent")
9.761 [ ERROR  ][loadComponent] Unable to create Orocos Component 'MyComponent': unknown component type.
 = false               

Deployer [S]>
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268969/how-to-load-orocos-component-by-loadcomponent-function?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2017-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think u have to create a deployer script for that i.e to load a component in a deployer. u can either use lua, ops or xml script for that. in ops script it will be:

```
loadComponent("your_component_name", "actual_component")
```

here u can check which components can be loaded by typing displayComponents in taskbrowser i.e inside deployer.
if u can't see the component which u want to load. than u have to first load the package which contains that component. For exampke if u have created that component inside a package named package_1 which may be ros package. Than u have to type:

```
import("package_1")
```

so that all the components which u have created inside this package will be avialabe in the taskborwser.

So all together:

1. import("package_name")
2. loadComponent("name_u_like", "component_name")
   thats all.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0